# Hide all but Selected Autodesk-Forge Viewer

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the forge viewer in a web application. I have made an isolate-part button. Currently when a part is isolated, it highlights that part and fades the rest of the model. Is there any way that when I isolate a part, the rest of the model can be completely hidden? I do not want the faded grey lines showing the rest of the model.
Thanks for the help! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can use the setGhosting() method on the viewer with a boolean parameter (true or false)

```
MyViewer.setGhosting(bool)
```